# angular material 2 table header center alignment

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

If md-sort-header is added into md-header-cell in md-table, it is always left-alignment. How to center-align header cells, such "name"?

```
<md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef md-sort-header style="text-align:center"> 
      Name 
</md-header-cell>
```

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7erAW9tUx9GExmruMeq3?p=preview)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Update for Angular Material 5.x.x, no need for ng-deep:

```
  mat-header-cell {
   display:flex;
   justify-content:flex-end;
  }
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iubspg-vqex6a)

---

`md-header-cell` get 'translated' to a container with class="mat-sort-header-container". Using that, you set its style with [**`ng-deep`**](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep). Use flexbox to center its content. Put the following in the components stylesheet:

```
::ng-deep .mat-sort-header-container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/J5WJa7RH5uBX8QHiJjQs?p=preview)

Comment: Works great. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I did have to use the ng-deep example with Angular 7 though.

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer is correct. However, `::ng-deep` is depreciated and maybe dropped in future ([official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)).

> The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is
>   being removed from major browsers and tools. As such we plan to drop
>   support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep). Until
>   then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader compatibility with
>   the tools.

The proper way is to use [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation). In your component.ts, add the following:

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    ....
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

and override the class in your component.css file:

```
.mat-sort-header-container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

Comment: :ng-deep is not depricated! it's /deep/ only. encapsulation may affect other classes

Comment: Please read the documentation: `The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is being removed from major browsers and tools. As such we plan to drop support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep).`

Comment: @Vega , I am not saying that your answer doesn't work, the OP may face an issue in future once  `::ng-deep` is dropped completely.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I wanted to add that if you want to center only one table header, then you can create your own custom class with name like `mat-sort-header-container-centered` with the outlined above css and assign it to your cell like this `<md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef md-sort-header class="mat-sort-header-container-centered">`

Comment: @DenissM. yes exactly :) I do the same and avoid using `::ng-deep`.

Comment: ::ng-deep is easier to use, and is it really depreciated?

Comment: I _think_ ::ng-deep is going to stay deprecated forever, and when it will be dropped an alternative will be provided. Until then, it's going to stay. It's been deprecated 3 versions ago and still going strong.

Comment: Avoid using `ViewEncapsulation.None` at all costs unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 8):

```
.mat-header-cell {    text-align: center;    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the given solutions to the problem are too strict in their approach, i had a similar issue where i needed to change some css properties of `mat-sort-header-container` , but dynamically.

I did something like Vega's answer but minutely different on how styles are taken :

```
::ng-deep .mat-sort-header-container{
    justify-content: inherit;
    /* other inheritable properties */
}
```

which opens some properties for its parent to style `mat-header-cell` which is in your html code so whatever style you provide in `mat-header-cell` and in the `ng-deep` which is inheriting from its parent then only those styles and none other than that would go down that hierarchy .

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want all header cells to align-center you can combine two classes:

```
.mat-header-cell.text-center { text-align: center; }
```

Then on the html:

```
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="text-center">Actions</th>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to align both the header and row cell content, on a column-by-column basis (allowing for differing alignments between columns), you could do something like this:

```
<mat-table>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="myColumn">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> My Column </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.myField}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
...
```

```
.mat-column-myColumn{
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: flex-start !important; /* Left aligned*/
}
```

The alignment is applied by the name specified in `matColumnDef`.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way, add this in your component css...

```
td {
  height: 8rem !important;
  text-align: center !important;
}

th {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center !important;
}
```