# How to align mat-cell content with icon to right on angular2/material?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

**To begin** with my Code:

```
<!-- Edit Column -->
<ng-container mdColumnDef="edit">
  <md-header-cell *mdHeaderCellDef> {{'companies.edit-column' | translate}}</md-header-cell>
  <md-cell *mdCellDef="let element"><a (click)="toCompany(element.id)"><md-icon class="md-dark">edit</md-icon></a></md-cell>
</ng-container>
```

**The Requirement** is to adjust the position of the edit icon to the right (with respect of material design's right padding)? Right now it appears to be forcibly left-docked. Applying a `style="{text-align: right}"`  to md-cell does not work.

**version of libs**:

```
"@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.10"
"@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
"@angular/common": "^4.1.3"
```

Comment: By any chance are you also using FlexLayout too? You can use the fxLayout directives here, positioning it with fxFlex shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The content of mat-cells are aligned to left by default. But you still can align them to center or right by redefining the display property. The following will align to right for ltr direction writing:

```
mat-cell{
  display:flex !important;
  justify-content:flex-end!important;
}
```

In the [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iubspg), the table cells are aligned to the right, while headers are still to the left

Comment: Worked as expected. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great! :) If you wish to align the headers too : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46155684/5468463