# How do I center Angular Material table column headers and mat-cell content

Tags: angular, angular-material

Can anyone provide a concise explanation of how to center (or move to the right) Angular Material table header and cell texts?  There seems to be a lot about needing /deep/ and other versions, which may or may not be deprecated.

Answer (score 22):

If no answer is working above then try this :

```
table {
  width: 100%;
}

mat-header-cell, mat-cell {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

**or**

[angular material 2 table header center alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46154838/angular-material-2-table-header-center-alignment/46155684)

Comment: I used both "justify-content: center;" and "text-align: center;". In my case, it's not enough to use just one.

Answer (score 14):

use this style with `!important`

```
th.mat-header-cell {
  text-align: center !important;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

This exactly works for mat-table.

```
td, th {
    text-align: center !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}

.mat-sort-header-container {
    justify-content: center !important;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this, It's work for me.

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-sort-header-container {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: this works very well 

Answer (score 6):

you can achieve that easily if you use this layout of table

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" style="width: 100%;">

   <!-- identification Column -->
   <ng-container matColumnDef="identification">
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </th>
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.identification}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- value Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="total">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Value </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.value | currency: 'ILS' }} </td>
  </ng-container>


  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

</table>
```

and put this in `where-the-table-is.component.css`

```
td.mat-cell, th.mat-header-cell {
    text-align: center;
    justify-content:center;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `text-align: center`

Here is an example [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hnuzvj?embed=1&file=app/table-basic-example.css) tweaked from the Material docs

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a sorted header you need to provide

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center !important;
}

.mat-sort-header-container{
    justify-content: center;
}

.mat-header-cell {
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

Comment: It appears only the CSS rule on .mat-sort-header-container is absolutely necessary.  FYI, define in the top level CSS, not a component's CSS file.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-sort-header-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

table {
  text-align: center !important;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me - I dont understand it - not come across :host ::ng-deep

Answer (score 2):

Try using class text-center

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="text-center"> {{element.multiplicador}} </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create css class

```
.centre {
  text-align: center
}
```

and add it to your html

```
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="centre"> Symbol </th>
```

just like here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qfav5c?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.css

Comment: Please mention the angular version? The stackblitz works nicely with a "td" element that has a mat-cell attribute.  In Angular 8 I'm using a "mat-cell" element directly, and I cannot make this solution work. Tried putting text-align:center into one of the dynamically created classes that the material table recognizes, also no luck.

Comment: @chrisinmtown as you can see this question is from 2018 so it was angular 1

Comment: @chrisinmtown : for recent Angular (8/9), you have to tell your component to use the "standard DOM" instead of the "shadow DOM" using `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in the `@Component` properties.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
td, th {
text-align: center !important;
vertical-align: middle !important;
}
:host ::ng-deep .mat-sort-header-container {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
.mat-header-cell {
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.mat-cell {
  text-align: center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```